# Caddy as reverse proxy to rewrite a http redirect url from an upstream response

Tags: reverse-proxy, caddy

I am having a backend that is not able when running behind a reverse proxy since I cannot configure a custom base URL.

For the login process the backend makes heavy use of HTTP redirects but due to the fact that is behind a reverse proxy it sends redirection URL that are not reachable by the client.

So I was wondering if there is a way to rewrite the upstream HTTP HEADER `Location`

If the backend responses

```
HTTP/1.1 301
Location: http://backend-hostname/auth/login
```

Caddy should rewrite the `Location` header to

```
HTTP/1.1 301
Location: http://www.my-super-site.com/service/a/auth/login
```

Is something like this possible?

I've that we can remove headers by declaring

```
header / {
    - Location
}
```

but it possible to replace the header and rewrite the URL?

Comment: https://caddyserver.com/docs/rewrite

Comment: As far as I understand this is about request rewriting. I am looking for a way to modify the proxied server's response

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for your question?

Comment: The Backend i got can be configured but should keep the internal domain. Curious too, any updates? @saw303

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for answer for this question and unfortunately I've found this responses:

https://caddy.community/t/v2-reverse-proxy-but-upstream-server-redirects-to-nonexistent-path/8566

https://caddy.community/t/proxy-url-not-loading-site/5393/7

***TLDR:***

You need to use sub-domains rather than sub-paths for services that are not design for being after proxy (or at least configure base URL). :(